# Can a delegate be used to call a method of a class without instantiating it?

Tags: c#, delegates

An interviewer asked me that he has got a heavy class with a number of methods.
He needs to have just one method as of now.

He asked me if Delegates in C# can help me calling that method without instantiating the class?

And he said Yes delegates can help us in this way.

I googled it. I tried running it on my VS but I guess I will need to initialize the class.

Have a look at this snippet -

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult test()
    {            
        NumberChanger nc1 = new NumberChanger( /*what to do here!
                                            can i call sum method of class abc*/);

        return View();
    }
}

public delegate int NumberChanger(int n, int m);

public class abc
{
    int a;
    int b;

    public int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use non-static method, probably you should use new NumberChanger(new abc().sum)
Have a try

Comment: thank you @mangusta, but here with new, we are instantiating the class

Comment: Well, I guess there is no way, if the method is not a member of the delegate method's class :/

Answer (score 0):

You always need at least 1 instance to call an instance method.

But if you want to avoid creating lots of heavy objects, you could use a trick like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    private static TestClass DummyInstance;

    public static Action GetShowAsDelegate()
    {
        DummyInstance = DummyInstance ?? new TestClass();
        return (DummyInstance.Show);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It works!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var show = TestClass.GetShowAsDelegate();
        show();
    }
}
```

Your class stores a private static instance of itself, which is instantiated when the caller asks for a delegate version of `Show()`. It then uses that instance, so you don't need to create one externally each time. After the first call, anyone can run the `Show` method by getting a delegate, without the need to create any more instances.

Comment: @Lakshay: No problem. I don't believe it's possible to do a lot better than this... AFAIK, you always need at least 1 instance to be able to invoke an instance method.